# Sequence that approximates union of N periodic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, periodic-functions

I have `N` monotonic sequences in the form of `tn[i] = Tn*i + Pn` (`Tn > 0, Pn >=0`), e.g.:

```
t1[i] = T1*i + P1
t2[j] = T2*j + P2
...
```

I need to find another sequence `s[k]` (not necessary in the same form) that approximates union of given sequences in such a way that:

1. For any sequence from the union `tn` and for any `i` there's such `k` that `|s[k] - tn[i]| < E`, where `E` is a given positive constant.
2. For any `k` following holds `s[k] - s[k-1] > D`, where `D` is a given positive constant.

How can I approach this class of problems? Engineer here, sorry if my terminology is off or if I didn't formalize the problem up to standards. I'm not even sure how to tag it.

The ultimate goal is to find minimal `E` (if it exists) for a given `D` (or for a given `E` find largest possible `D`).

Below is example for two sequences `t1[j] = 5j` and `t2[i] = 6i` with `E=1.5` and `D=4.5` (I don't think that's the optimal solution, but just to illustrate what I'm after).

[image: example]

Comment: I don't quite understand requirement 2: isn't $t_n[i]-t_n[i-1]=T_n$, so it looks like you have no control over it whatsoever. Am I missing something or have you written something different from what you meant?

Comment: @fedja Sorry, my mistake, corrected. I meant `s[k] - s[k-1] > D`. Basically, all members in `s` are at least `D` apart.

Comment: I still think that you meant $s[k]-s[k-1]$. Is it correct?

Comment: @fedja Yes, you read my reply too fast, I corrected two times :)

Comment: Ah, OK. As they say "one picture is worth a thousand words" :-) OK, now everything makes sense and I'll think of it.

Comment: FYI - your original sequences are *arithmetic*, not  “periodic” (which means they repeat a set of values forever - arithmetic means they increase by the same amount each step).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Apparently, what is meant is that there is some $T$ that is a common multiple of $T_n$, and $s$, probably, should also satisfy $s[k+mq]=s[k]+mT$ for some $q$, so you can view the problem as if it were posed on the circle. It is easy to check if $E$ and $D$ are compatible for $D>4E$, so the interesting case is $2E<D<4E$.

Comment: @fedja - I was just giving a terminology correction. The original sequences are mono tonic. No periodic sequence can estimate them beyond one cycle.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand. I just wanted to explain what (IMO) the OP meant by "periodic" (i.e., that this word made certain sense and wasn't a mere slip of tongue). Anyway, let's try to figure it out :-)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for correction, I called sequences periodic because they model periodic signals (like a sensor scans each T seconds). So, N sensors, each scans at certain rate (period `Tn`) and has its own phase (`+ Pn` component). Certain information needs to be communicated to sensors in `E` proximity around the scan time and communication channel favors less frequent communications (the requirement for batching and largest `D`).